# Versioning rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, versioning

(Didn't get much of an answer on the database administrators group, so trying my luck here)

So I have this concept in my head of "immutable" records, which I am sure is not novel, but can't seem to find the right google keywords.

Basically, historical row values need to be preserved as 'obsolete', but remain referencable as FKs from older records. These types of modifications are **infrequent**. I'm using MySQL, which limits things a bit.  The four approaches I see are:

***Naive***

- PK is an auto-generated ID
- obsolete_stamp is a timestamp indicating    that the row values are
  obsolete

Drawback: historical data is preserved, but there is no way to track history of changes

***Better***:

- PK same as above
- old_id is the id of the row that this row modifies (if exists)
- obsolete_stamp (null if row data is current)

consequence: new rows are modifications of old rows, but the new rows have to update the old_id (if there is one)

***audit***:

- an on update trigger creates a new row in an audit table

drawback: queries will need to check audit table for obsoleted rows

***compound key:***

- id + obsolete_stamp

drawback: id can't be generated anew, only if the row is 'novel' (no history); not clear how to do that automatically.

I'm moving ahead with the "better" option, which seems the simplest way to track revision history.

Answer (score 2):

How about maintaining a table of the current entities along with a history table?

You would insert into this table using `on duplicate key update`.  It would have an auto-incremented id that identifies each entity.

It would also have an `insert`/`update` trigger.  When a new row is inserted (or an older row is overwritten), then the row would be written to the history table.

The history table could have a unique id for the history table, an insertion date/time, and all the columns of interest.  Rows in this table would never be modified.

Comment: Gordon, I think that is similar to, of not the same as, the audit table. The only drawback I can see is that two tables need to be queried to find a row: the current data table and the audit data table.  Every solution has its tradeoffs, though.

BTW, the `on duplicate key update` idea I hadn't considered.  That could be useful.

Comment: @JeffLowery . . . Not at all.  You are inserting the row in the audit table when the row is created.  It is in both tables.

Comment: Right, I missed that.